# fp-ts: How do I "pull up" a nested `Either`/`TaskEither` to the outer type?

Tags: typescript, fp-ts

I am learning some `fp-ts`. To create a stylized version of an issue I'm having, assume I want to create a table if it doesn't exist, so I must query the database: a fallible, async operation. If that table doesn't exist, I want to create it: another fallible, async operation. Assume further that the error types are both strings (though I'd also like to know how to create a union error type if needed), and that the value returned on successful creation is a numerical ID.

In short, see if the table is there, if it isn't, create it—with errors a possibility all along the way. The key is that I want both errors reflected in the outermost type: a `TaskEither<string, Option<number>>`. The problem is that I'm not sure how to avoid getting a `TaskEither<string, Option<TaskEither<string, number>>>`. That is, I don't know the best way to pull the error inside the `Option` up and coalesce it into the outermost error.

(Perhaps this involves sequences or traversables? I'm still learning about those.)

On to some code:

```ts
import { taskEither as TE, option as O } from "fp-ts";
import { pipe } from "fp-ts/lib/function";

// tableExists: () => TE.TaskEither<string, boolean>
// createTable: () => TE.TaskEither<string, number>

// I want this to represent both possible errors. Currently a type error.
// -------------------------------vvvvvv
const example = (): TE.TaskEither<string, O.Option<number>> => {
  return pipe(
    tableExists(),
    // How to pull the possible `left` up to the outermost type?
    // ------------------------------------------vvvvvvvvvvvvv
    TE.map((exists) => (exists ? O.none : O.some(createTable()))
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I figured this out, though of course welcome any corrections.

Rather than "pulling" the `TaskEither` up from within the `Option`, I think I needed to "push" the `Option` down into the nested `TaskEither` so that the nesting put the layers of `TaskEither`s next to each other, allowing flattening them via `chain`.

```ts
const example = (): TE.TaskEither<string, O.Option<number>> =>
  pipe(
    tableExists(),
    TE.chain((exists) =>
      exists
        ? TE.of(O.none)
        : pipe(
            createTable(),
            TE.map(O.of)
          )
    )
  );
```

My side question about what I'd do if the error types were different also appears to be handled by this code, except `TE.chainW` replaces `TE.chain`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you figured it out on your own :) In case it's helpful, I've implemented the example with the error as a discriminated union so that you can easily identify which error occurred when you call `example`.

```
import * as TE from 'fp-ts/lib/TaskEither'
import * as O from 'fp-ts/lib/Option'
import { pipe } from "fp-ts/lib/function";

declare const tableExists: () => TE.TaskEither<string, boolean>
declare const createTable: () => TE.TaskEither<string, number>

// Discriminated union so you can easily identify which error it is
type ExampleErr = { tag: "TableExistsError", error: unknown } | { tag: "CreateTableError", error: unknown }

const example = (): TE.TaskEither<ExampleErr, O.Option<number>> => {
  return pipe(
    tableExists(),
    TE.mapLeft(error => ({ tag: "TableExistsError" as const, error })),
    TE.chainW(exists => exists ?
      TE.right(O.none) :
      pipe(
        createTable(),
        TE.mapLeft(error => ({ tag: "CreateTableError" as const, error })),
        TE.map(O.some)
      )
    )
  );
};
```

You correctly identified that you need to use `chainW` if the error types from `tableExists` and `createTable` are different. The `W` at the end of a function in `fp-ts` means "widen" and it generally allows the type to widen to the union of two types. In the case of `chainW` for `TaskEither`, that means that the error type will become the union of the two `TaskEither` types (the one going into `chainW` and the one being returned inside it).

Understanding when to use `map` and when to use `chain` is a fundamental concept that is important to understand well. `map` allows you to modify a value inside your structure, it's a simple function from `A -> B`. `chain` allows you to perform another effect which relies on the result of the first one - so you must return a value which is wrapped by the same effect you are dealing with. In this case you are working with `TaskEither`, so the function you pass to `chain` also needs to be of type `A -> TaskEither<E, B>` (which `createTable` is, but you also need to manually handle the case where the table already exists and construct the TaskEither there using `TE.right(O.none)` or `TE.of(O.none)`).

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for that! I know a bit of Rust, and it's interesting to see the same or similar concepts here (`map`; `and_then`/`chain`; etc.). And while I still don't fully grasp the _theory_ of monads, functors, applicatives, etc., I'm understanding their value and use from a practical perspective by seeing those theories put into practice through language/library constructs like these. Very cool stuff!